# Problem with number entry QGIS modeler

Tags: qgis, algorithm, qgis-modeler, model

i created some number entry in QGIS modeler    [image]

I created them specifically for them to be decimal numbers and not integer. [image]

But when i try my model, when i put a decimal number like 0.255 the value on the screen stays at 0. So it doesn't want to have decimal but just integer. [image]

Do someone has an idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Set the **Default value** to 0.0.

[image: Number parameter]

This tells QGIS that the number parameter should be read as a decimal value. So when you run the model, you should see the decimal value in the input parameter:

[image: Running model]

---

*Note: The Min/Max values can be left blank but will cause an error if they are filled with the string `None`. This occurs when you load the parameter settings again without setting those values.*